# Customize JTextField border when focused - Nimbus

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, look-and-feel, nimbus

My app is working with Nimbus LAF but my problem is that, because I am using `JTextfield` with height dimension of 17 the heavy border when focused, it is cutting half of the text.
On the other hand I looked on the text field when using Metal LAF,
it works perfect, the border not cover the text at all.

Can I customize the text field to Metal behavior when using Nimbus?  If so, how?

Comment: How can I do it ?, e.g. for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame and JTextField

Comment: *"My app is working with Nimbus LAF but my problem is that, .."* .. the app is working with Nimbus LAF!  Some would say that Nimbus is a problematic LAF that breaks many rules - and it shows at times like this.

Comment: First comment is from someone that didn't read what I wrote, because nothing wrong with my code I just asked if I can cast simple JTextField to metal while working with nimbus and how / that it

Comment: as for our second guy thank u for telling me that I have a problem, without u I couldn't see it but this is not my question, my question is how to solve it

Comment: *"without u I couldn't see it but this is not my question"*  It is the *problem* though..  *"because nothing wrong with my code"*  @mKorbel recommended you post an MCVE so that others who think they can solve it have code to experiment with.  Voting to close as having no MCVE.

Comment: Here is my code 
`TField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170,17));` please do not tell me not to use setPreferredSize

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.coderanch.com/t/643512/GUI/java/Customize-JTextField-border-focused-Nimbus#2957422)